# Implement logging levels for aws lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, logging, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

What is the recommended way to implement logging levels for aws lambda functions in nodejs. I was going through many third party libraries e.g winston, winston cloudwatch, logplease, but it seems like we can also achieve using the native console. e.g

```
console.log(), console.error(), console.warn(), console.info()
```

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Lambda console output goes directly into CloudWatch Logs, you really don't need to use something like Winston CloudWatch if that is your preferred log destination. If you wanted to send the logs somewhere else like Loggly then you might want to use something like Winston Loggly.

However, even if you just want to send all console output to CloudWatch Logs, I would still recommend using a basic Winston configuration, so that you could quickly and easily enable debug logging, for example through an environment variable, and then turn off debug logging once you are ready to use the Lambda function in production.

Comment: Is it possible to control the log leve of nodej lambda's without using any third party libraries (e.g. Winston)?

Comment: @kk not without a bunch of `if` statements wrapped around every log statement.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant code is here:

https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-nodejs-runtime-interface-client/blob/a850fd5adad5f32251350ce23ca2c8934b2fa542/src/utils/LogPatch.ts#L69-L89

So, you can use 7 console methods to get 6 CloudWatch log levels:

```
FATAL: console.fatal()
ERROR: console.error()
WARN: console.warn()
INFO: console.info() or console.log()
DEBUG: console.debug()
TRACE: console.trace()
```

`console.trace()` doesn't produce the same trace it produces in plain Node 14
`console.fatal()` is missing in plain Node 14, it's added by the AWS Lambda Runtime

This was tested with the Node 14.x runtime on Aug 25 2022. YMMV.